# OpenXR and valve index trigger value

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

*EDIT* updated code
I've been looking for quite some time how to get valve index trigger value to be read.

This is the current code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class XRHand : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputActionProperty triggerAction;
    private float triggerValue;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        triggerValue = triggerAction.action.ReadValue<float>();
        Debug.Log("Trigger from "+gameObject.name+": " + triggerValue);
    }
}
```

This works in HTC Vive but not in Valve index when pressing the trigger.

I've prefabs lefthand and righthand. In lefthand we use `XRI LeftHand Interaction/Activate Value` as `triggerAction` and XRI RightHand in righthand.

Any idea where to get started?

Unity version: 2021.3.21f1

OpenXR Plugin: 1.6.0

XR Interaction Toolkit: 2.2.0

Comment: Have you tried to look at the examples? https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/XR-Interaction-Toolkit-Examples And should you not bind those to actions instead of trying to read from the controller?

Comment: What is happening and what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to read the trigger float value from 0 to 1. Which is happening with HTC Vive but not with Valve Index

Comment: I tried now with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PCNNro7Rt0 to read the trigger value as described in updated code. With htc vive we get values from 0 to 1 as expected, but with index it's always 0

Comment: @Evorlor any chance that you've been able to read trigger from index controllers wth openxr?

Comment: @joonasj I haven't worked with the Vive in years, so I don't remember anything about it.  I think my comment was just at attempt to get more details to help others answer.

Comment: @Evorlor yeah the problem isn't with HTC VIVE, that works out of the box like it should. Probelm is the Valve Index. Head and hand movement works with Index without any issues but we can't read trigger or any other button from Valve Index when using openXR